# Azure PowerShell Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServiceObjective returns null when specifying certain Premium performance levels

Tags: powershell, azure

I've created an Azure PowerShell script in a Runbook within the Azure Automation portal in order to automatically scale the database performance level depending on what time it is.

I can successfully retrieve a service objective via "Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServiceObjective" when I want to scale down to a "P1" or "P2" performance level; however, when I want to scale up to "P6" or "P11", I am unable to do so with the same exact block of code:

```
$Edition = "Premium"
$PerfLevel = "P6"
$Servercredential = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Credential.UserName, (($Credential).GetNetworkCredential().Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force))  

$CTX = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ManageUrl “https://$ServerName.database.windows.net” -Credential $ServerCredential  
$ServiceObjective = Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServiceObjective $CTX -ServiceObjectiveName $PerfLevel

Set-AzureSqlDatabase $CTX –DatabaseName $DatabaseName –ServiceObjective $ServiceObjective –Edition $Edition -Force
```

When I specify "P6" as the "ServiceObjectiveName" this cmdlet returns null; however, when I specify "P1" or P2" the cmdlet returns the correct ServiceObjective object, and the code will execute properly.

The MSDN documentation for "Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServiceObjective" only shows "P1, P2, P3" as valid Premium values; however, there has to be a way to scale the database to these higher performance levels (I can specify "P3" as a parameter in this script and it will actually change the database performance level to P3, even though you can't select this performance level manually through the Azure Portal anymore).

Can anyone give advice or maybe another method to achieve scaling up to these higher performance levels via a PowerShell script? I've done hours of research on here and elsewhere and I can't find a solution to this or any other post with a similar problem that was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Resource Management commandlet for sql server i.e [Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.sql/v2.3.0/set-azurermsqldatabase) can be used to upscale db to any desired edition/performance level.

We have to connect to our Azure subscription and acquire database instance to upscale it. We can create a [runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-starting-a-runbook) to schedule upgrade/downgrade.

```
# Read the subscription credentials. AzureRunAsConnection asset is created as a part of Automation account setup(see link below)
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection 

# Connect to the subscription (Uninteractive login).
Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID `
                        -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID `
                        -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint

# Set the new performance tier of db.
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase -DatabaseName $Using:DatabaseName `
                        -ServerName $Using:SqlServerName `
                        -ResourceGroupName $Using:ResourceGroupName `
                        -Edition $Using:Edition `
                        -RequestedServiceObjectiveName $Using:PerfLevel
```

Read [Authentication runbook with AzureRunAsAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-sec-configure-azure-runas-account) for details on authentication using runbook connection asset.

**NOTE**: `(tick) is used to break the commandlet in multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my upgrade and downgrade example for Azure DB and Azure DWH: http://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2017/04/scheduled-upgrade-and-downgrade-azure.html
[image]